# 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown in ZipArchive for large file from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stream

I have an URL which contains a zip file. The files need to be unzipped from the URL. The URL is Opened and Read using webclient and then added to a Stream. It is then used in the ZipArchive object which will unzip the files and store them in the D:\ drive. When a file is around 400Mb I get the **'System.OutOfMemoryException'**.

Stream has to be used since the webClient.OpenRead(Uri Address) returns a Stream. As well as the use ZipArchive(Stream stream).

[image]

How can I stop from getting this message?

```
 string zipFileUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/clersbjdcshpdy6/oversize_zip_test_0.zip?dl=0"
 string output_path = @"D:\";

 using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
 {

     using (Stream streamFile = webClient.OpenRead(zipFileUrl))
     {
          using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(streamFile))//ERROR HERE
          {                                 
              var entries = archive.Entries;
              //Loops thru each file in Zip and adds it to directory
              foreach (var entry in entries)
              {
                 if (entry.FullName != "/" && entry.Name != "")
                 {

                    string completeFileName = Path.Combine(output_path, entry.FullName);
                    string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName);

                     //If directory does not exist then we create it.
                     if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                     {
                         Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                     }
                     //Extracts zip from URL to extract path, and overwrites if file exists. 
                     entry.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);                                                         
                }
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: I am very surprised you get the error on `OpenRead`, opening the stream for reading should not take up that much memory.

Comment: What is the StackTrace?

Comment: Getting no error like that at my end, though I do get `End of Central Directory record could not be found` on the next line.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I get the error in using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(streamFile)

Comment: Thats what I thought, see the answer I provided for solutions to that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [here might be your problem](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.Compression/src/System/IO/Compression/ZipArchive.cs#L481-487), from the `ZipArchive.Init` method

```
private void Init(Stream stream, ZipArchiveMode mode, Boolean leaveOpen)
{
    Stream extraTempStream = null;

    try
    {
        _backingStream = null;

        //check stream against mode
        switch (mode)
        {
            case ZipArchiveMode.Create:
                // (SNIP)
            case ZipArchiveMode.Read:
                if (!stream.CanRead)
                    throw new ArgumentException(SR.ReadModeCapabilities);
                if (!stream.CanSeek)
                {
                    _backingStream = stream;
                    extraTempStream = stream = new MemoryStream();
                    _backingStream.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                }
                break;
            case ZipArchiveMode.Update:
                // (SNIP)
            default:
                // (SNIP)
        }
     // (SNIP)
}
```

if `streamFile.CanSeek` is false (which from a WebClient it will be) it copies the entire file in to memory then works on the file. This is what is using up all the memory.

Try to find a 3rd party library that handles Zip files and does not need a stream that supports seeking. If you can't, copy the file to disk first to the temp folder with a `FileStream` with the [`FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option passed in, then use that stream in your zip before you close the stream.

```
string zipFileUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/clersbjdcshpdy6/oversize_zip_test_0.zip?dl=0";
string output_path = @"D:\";

using (var tempFileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempFileName(), FileMode.Create, 
                                           FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 
                                           4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
    using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        using (Stream streamFile = webClient.OpenRead(zipFileUrl))
        {
            streamFile.CopyTo(tempFileStream);
        }
    }
    tempFileStream.Position = 0;
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(tempFileStream))
    {
        var entries = archive.Entries;
        //Loops thru each file in Zip and adds it to directory
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            if (entry.FullName != "/" && entry.Name != "")
            {

                string completeFileName = Path.Combine(output_path, entry.FullName);
                string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName);

                //If directory does not exist then we create it.
                if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
                }
                //Extracts zip from URL to extract path, and overwrites if file exists. 
                entry.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Copying the file to the temp location first and then unzipping worked great Scott. I should of thought of that first. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Has this been fixed in 2020 can you read it from a url now using getentry?